# Please change the text on "Citizen Patrol" to what it actually does

Tags: discussion, badges, flagging-badges

I just flagged a question as off-topic on SO.  On not getting the badge I checked here and gathered that *apparently* (seen no official comment) it's only awared for flagging spam/offensive.  So... shouldn't the badge say so?

Oh, and given *that*, should it really be only bronze?  I've only seen one spam post so far (not on SO), so I think they're quite a bit rarer than off-topic posts.

(Hmm, I do have to check where I (should) have gotten that CP badge...)

Comment: Spam on SO is common enough - even discounting people shilling their own products - I'm talking about people flogging shoes and such.

Comment: So, who downvoted this just now?  Smacks of revenge-voting, or is there an actual reason to downvote?

Comment: Actually, since the CP was changed yesterday, this is moot: it now seems to be awarded for exactly what the text says, not just for "spam/off".

Answer (score 5):

Spam is taken care of quickly on SO so that is why you haven't seen much of it.

I think bronze is appropriate because it doesn't it take long to earn it all just flagging a single post.  Which lines up with Bronze's description:

> Bronze badges are awarded for basic
>   use of Stack Overflow; they are easy
>   to earn.

However, I agree with your statement that the text is misleading, it just says first flagged post.  It should say something like: first flagged spam/offensive post.

Answer (score 3):

Now [flagging for moderator attention also counts for the Citizen Patrol badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74243/187824). So there is no need to change the [text for this badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) which reads:

> #### First flagged post.