# Citizen Patrol badge is not awarded on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, badges, flagging-badges

I started flagging from 12th July 2013. Now I have 15 helpful flags in my Meta profile. But still I didn't receive the  [Citizen Patrol](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol) badge for first flagged post. However I received same on Stack Overflow after flagging my first post.

Comment: Yeah, Same happened to me also.

Comment: hmm, same here as well..

Comment: Looks like a major problem.

Comment: @RalZarek, according to OP's [comment on his question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75048/please-change-the-text-on-citizen-patrol-to-what-it-actually-does#comment192186_75048), the mismatch was fixed. But perhaps there's a regression.

Comment: @doubleDown Oh right, missed the answer that it is now for all flags. There were some bugs with the close flags since the closing/flagging changes, so it is probably something with those.

Comment: says you earned it here though http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol?userId=227860

Comment: @m0sa, ahhh. then why it is not showing in my profile http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/227860/vigbyor?tab=badges

Comment: @m0sa - There appears to be a bug in that page - it appears to tell _every_ user that they have earned the badge. For example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/publicist?userId=227860

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The badge criteria was changed by mistake - it took into account many less flags than it should have.

This has now been corrected (next build) and once the badge award schedule runs, you should have it.

Comment: OP here still didn't get the badge - bug in the fix? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Dunno, will have to take a look tomorrow morning.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, agree, I got nice question badge instead of Citizen Patrol badge :P

Comment: @Vigbyor yeah, that's my own doing. (10th upvote is mine ;))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, jee thanks, Finally I got my badge :)

Comment: Cheers @Vigbyor it's even retroactive! Oded is this your doing or have the scheduled task run just now? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Combination of both ;)