# Has Citizen Patrol Badge location changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, profile-page, flagging-badges

In my Stack Overflow [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2567598/vigbyor?tab=badges) we can see that Citizen Patrol badge is there. Now I have same badge on meta site too but instead of showing this badge in my meta [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/227860/vigbyor?tab=badges), it is showing [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol?userId=227860).

Is this a bug or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) ?

Comment: It should show in both pages. It is a bug.

Comment: @hims056 - The user profile is cached. For 10 minutes, IIRC.

Comment: @Oded 10 Mins ?? I raised my first flag on 12th July. Currently I have 25 helpful flags in my profile, and I am on the way to earn  Deputy Badge in few days

Comment: When were you awarded the badge?

Comment: @Oded - also see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188930/187824

Comment: @Oded , I dont know, Moderator Mosa just showed me that link.

Comment: Interesting. In the particular badge page for any user it shows timestamp of when it was awarded. E.g. [myself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol?userid=187824). But there is no timestamp in [yours](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol?userId=227860)

Comment: @hims056, Thanks, its good point or may be another bug.

Comment: caching, a proven way to optimize user complaints. _- It doesn't work!!! - Probably caching, wait for 5 minutes. - It doesn't work!! - Probably caching, wait for 5 minutes. - It doesn't work! - Probably caching, wait for 5 minutes. - It doesn't work. - Probably caching, wait for 5 minutes. - It doesn't matter._

Comment: @Vigbyor I bet you never flagged a post here on Meta. Is this correct?

Comment: OK, the bug is in the citizen patrol page when it has a user ID it will **always** show as if the user got the badge. [This is proof enough](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol?userId=228439) - user with only 1 reputation while one [needs 15 points](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to flag. @Oded to your attention as well.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [26 helpful flags](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S7ni5.png)

Comment: @Vigbyor - That's a different issue. The issue is that you _should_ have been awarded the badge and were not.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Correct. I just confirmed that.

Comment: oh Man, I am confused ? have I earned the badge or not ???

Comment: Well, you found two bugs that's quite impressive! One bug is no badge even though you should have earned it and another one that you discovered by chance.

Comment: @Vigbyor - You did not earn the badge, though you should have. In that respect, your profile page is correct, but the single badge page is not (as things stand). Once the badge is awarded, both pages should show it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, since there is change in the old flagging system, I believe this is the result of it.

Comment: @Oded ha ha that means Mosa just fooled me by showing that link :P

Comment: @Vigbyor might be. Hmm.. did you by any chance flag only comments? The badge is awarded only for flagging *posts* as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, not yet, I just flagged post only, and link only answers on main site.

Comment: Yes. He was not aware of this bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug on the single badge page. It is showing that you have earned the badge when, in fact you didn't.

For example, you did not earn the Publicist badge:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/76/publicist?userId=227860

It appears that if a valid `userId` is passed in to the page, the words "earned this badge" show up, whether one did or did not. However, if the badge **had** been awarded, a date will also appear.

This will be fixed soon.

Comment: I wonder what is the expected behavior though? Showing "this user did not earn this badge", or just redirecting to the badge page?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I would say - did not earn sounds moar correkt

Comment: @Oded or I would say, showing a "" blank space is better.

Comment: @Vigbyor - Having words makes sure the page is not ambiguous.

Comment: @Oded agree but displaying negative message ( did not earn ) doesn't sound good user interface as per my experience.

Comment: @Vigbyor - true enough. "Yet to be earned" ;)

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to @Oded's answer for details.

The bug is fixed and it will be out in the next deployment.