# Eeeek! The Space Exploration row in the All Sites list is borked!

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

I'm pretty sure we didn't do anything over at Space Exploration, but we just got all our questions and answers taken away:

[image]

This makes it look like we have the most unengaged audience in the history of mankind. Could it be fixed?

Comment: Space is unbounded right? NaN makes *perfect* sense...

Comment: Yet somehow you're still averaging 8 questions/day.

Comment: @Emrakul I know - apparently 0/30days now equals 7.9?

Comment: could be a case of http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47593/the-paranormal-files

Comment: Interesting, since the stats in the sidebar on [the site itself](http://space.stackexchange.com/) are fine.

Comment: [Bork, Bork...](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DsY_Yf4zz-yo&ei=x9MDUuWRBsXuyQHdtIHgBg&usg=AFQjCNF5Jq-3fnSdsoKRgE7gAKFopgEpzQ&sig2=APfU2481a-Tpo_rkT45SvQ&bvm=bv.50500085,d.aWc)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm going to blame caching on this one.  I'm looking at it now and I see stats.

Also, space - http://thefinalfrontier.stackexchange.com

Comment: How about [SPAAAAAAACE](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/524904249274121803/4C3CF0C00C76A83B94F84DEF48141E73EEE8AB3C/268x268.resizedimage)?

Comment: caching, [a proven way to optimize user complaints...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189127/has-citizen-patrol-badge-location-changed#comment583495_189127)

Answer (score 18):

> It is known that there are an infinite number of worlds, simply because there is an infinite amount of space for them to be in. However, not every one of them is inhabited. Therefore, there must be a finite number of inhabited worlds. Any finite number divided by infinity is as near to nothing as makes no odds, so the average population of all the planets in the Universe can be said to be zero. From this it follows that the population of the whole Universe is also zero, and that any people you may meet from time to time are merely the products of a deranged imagination.

— [Douglas Adams](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Chapter_19)

Comment: Doesn't compute (though I like hitchhikers guide) as infinity can have subsets that are themselves infinite. In fact there is an example of that in the quote. Space is a infinite set and the planets are an infinite subset of that set. Which means that you could have an infinite subset of the planets that are populated.  (ps I didn't do the -1, just wanted to point out the above).

Comment: @ryan I think that's part of the joke: the Guide, after all, ["has many omissions and contains much that is apocryphal, or at least wildly inaccurate"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Introduction). I can understand the downvote, wherever it's from - a little surprised to have a positive balance TBH.

Answer (score 3):

## Division by Cucumber!

### Reinstall Universe^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^HStack Exchange and reboot

Comment: +++OUT OF CHEESE ERROR+++