# Why is Raghav Sood's accounts count showing zero in his profile-page?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, information-display

See his [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1069068/raghav-sood).

Why is it showing like that?

All his profiles are showing like this. See his [meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187954/raghav-sood).

Comment: Wait for sometimes it will show again. This happened with me 2-3 times. Not sure why.

Comment: I see 23 accounts on his profile page.

Comment: @Oded - But *sometimes* it shows 0 accounts for *few moments*.

Comment: `[status-dismissed]`

Comment: make a screenshot next time

Comment: `[status-caching]`, ["a proven way to optimize user complaints..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189127/has-citizen-patrol-badge-location-changed#comment583495_189127)

Comment: @Dirty-flow I doubt that would have stopped Oded from tagging this as `norepo` -- he surely knows that this does happen.

Comment: @hims056 - the page gets cached for a minute, so unless it stays like that for longer...